# Error when trying to insert row to table because of UUID foreign key with sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize.js with node.js and postgres.
I got 2 simple tables from an example as a 'POC' of sorts.
I changed the ID to be UUID and I am having an issue with the insert into the second table ( with the UUID FK ).

I am using postman to test it. 
I am creating todo rows with UUID with no issues,
Then I am trying to create a todo item which has a todo id as foreign key
and it seems that it is failing to recognize that ID!

I tried a manual script in postgres and it worked. 
I am probably missing something code wise but I cant figure out what.

here is the error which is being returned to me in postman -

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
    "parent": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 96,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "file": "uuid.c",
        "line": "137",
        "routine": "string_to_uuid",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;"
    },
    "original": {
        "name": "error",
        "length": 96,
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "22P02",
        "file": "uuid.c",
        "line": "137",
        "routine": "string_to_uuid",
        "sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;"
    },
    "sql": "INSERT INTO \"TodoItems\" (\"id\",\"content\",\"complete\",\"createdAt\",\"updatedAt\",\"todoId\") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6) RETURNING *;"
}
```

Here are the relevant js files -

todoItems.js controller -

```
const TodoItem = require('../dal/models').TodoItem;
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return TodoItem
      .create({
        content: req.body.content,
        todoId: req.params.todoId,
      })
      .then(todoItem => res.status(201).send(todoItem))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  update(req, res) {
    return TodoItem
      .find({
        where: {
          id: req.params.todoItemId,
          todoId: req.params.todoId,
        },
      })
      .then(todoItem => {
        if (!todoItem) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'TodoItem Not Found',
          });
        }

        return todoItem
          .update({
            content: req.body.content || todoItem.content,
            complete: req.body.complete || todoItem.complete,
          })
          .then(updatedTodoItem => res.status(200).send(updatedTodoItem))
          .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  destroy(req, res) {
    return TodoItem
      .find({
        where: {
          id: req.params.todoItemId,
          todoId: req.params.todoId,
        },
      })
      .then(todoItem => {
        if (!todoItem) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'TodoItem Not Found',
          });
        }

        return todoItem
          .destroy()
          .then(() => res.status(204).send())
          .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

todos.js controller-

```
const Todo = require('../dal/models').Todo;
const TodoItem = require('../dal/models').TodoItem;

module.exports = {
  create(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .create({
        title: req.body.title,
      })
      .then((todo) => res.status(201).send(todo))
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  list(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .findAll({
        include: [{
          model: TodoItem,
          as: 'todoItems',
        }],
        order: [
          ['createdAt', 'DESC'],
          [{ model: TodoItem, as: 'todoItems' }, 'createdAt', 'ASC'],
        ],
      })
      .then((todos) => res.status(200).send(todos))
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  retrieve(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .findByPk(req.params.todoId, {
        include: [{
          model: TodoItem,
          as: 'todoItems',
        }],
      })
      .then((todo) => {
        if (!todo) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'Todo Not Found',
          });
        }
        return res.status(200).send(todo);
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  update(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .findByPk(req.params.todoId, {
        include: [{
          model: TodoItem,
          as: 'todoItems',
        }],
      })
      .then(todo => {
        if (!todo) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'Todo Not Found',
          });
        }
        return todo
          .update({
            title: req.body.title || todo.title,
          })
          .then(() => res.status(200).send(todo))
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },

  destroy(req, res) {
    return Todo
      .findByPk(req.params.todoId)
      .then(todo => {
        if (!todo) {
          return res.status(400).send({
            message: 'Todo Not Found',
          });
        }
        return todo
          .destroy()
          .then(() => res.status(204).send())
          .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
      })
      .catch((error) => res.status(400).send(error));
  },
};
```

todo table create migration -

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    }),
  down: (queryInterface /* , Sequelize */) => queryInterface.dropTable('Todos'),
};
```

todo-item table create migration -

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) =>
    queryInterface.createTable('TodoItems', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
      },
      content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      complete: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      todoId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        references: {
          model: 'Todos',
          key: 'id',
          as: 'todoId',
        },
      },
    }),
  down: (queryInterface /* , Sequelize */) =>
    queryInterface.dropTable('TodoItems'),
};
```

todo model -

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  });
  Todo.associate = (models) => {
    Todo.hasMany(models.TodoItem, {
      foreignKey: 'todoId',
      as: 'todoItems',
    });
  };
  Todo.beforeCreate((item, _ ) => {
    return item.id = uuid();
  });
  return Todo;
};
```

todo-item model -

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const TodoItem = sequelize.define('TodoItem', {
    content: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    complete: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    }
  });
  TodoItem.associate = (models) => {
    TodoItem.belongsTo(models.Todo, {
      foreignKey: 'todoId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    });
  };
  TodoItem.beforeCreate((item, _ ) => {
    return item.id = uuid();
  });
  return TodoItem;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your router code look like? Are you using correct path parameter for todoId? If you're using express for example. it should look like `app.post("/todos/:todoId/todo_items", todoItemController.create)` . Note the camelcase todoId . That will ensure that the `req.params.todoId` you're referencing in todoItems controller would have the right value.

Also, make sure you have a correct body parser to handle req.body.content correctly. In express, this would be done via body body-parser library and `app.use(bodyParser.json())` . Add a breakpoint or log statement in the todoItem controller create code and verify that you actually have the correct parameter values.

Comment: Sadly I removed the todo items code and replaced it with my real models so I cant know for sure but things are working well now.
I am pretty sure the issue was indeed related to bad naming in the router paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have the error above, it might be because you are nesting other entities in your request body and therefore the UUID is not getting converted from string to a UUID.

For instance if you have a request body like

```
{
   "Transaction": {
      "id" : "f2ec9ecf-31e5-458d-847e-5fcca0a90c3e",
      "currency" : "USD",
      "type_id" : "bfa944ea-4ce1-4dad-a74e-aaa449212ebf", 
      "total": 8000.00,
      "fees": 43.23,
      "description":"Description here"
    },
}
```

and therefore in your controller you are creating your entity like

```
try {
  await Transaction.create(
    {
      id: req.body.Transaction.id,
      currency: req.body.Transaction.currency,
      type_id: req.body.Transaction.type_id,
      total: req.body.Transaction.total,
      fees: req.body.Transaction.fees,
      description: req.body.Transaction.description,
    }......
```

Your `id` and `type_id` are mostly likely not being converted from string to a UUID.

There are multiple ways of tackling this. The most straightforward approach is to do an explicit conversion from string to UUID.

To do this, import `parse` from the `uuid npm module` and do the explicit conversion as you can see in the code sample below.

```
const { parse: uuidParse } = require("uuid");
try {
  await Transaction.create(
    {
      id: uuidParse(req.body.Transaction.id),
      currency: req.body.Transaction.currency,
      type_id: uuidParse(req.body.Transaction.type_id),
      total: req.body.Transaction.total,
      fees: req.body.Transaction.fees,
      description: req.body.Transaction.description,
    }.....
```

This explicit conversion from string to a UUID will mostly solve the issue.